# Accessing "neighbor" classes created from 1 class possible?

Tags: c++

Here's my problem:

I have 1 class that creates two new instances of a two other classes, and now I would need to either have a direct availability from one of the instances to the other, is this possible and if so, how?

so:

in Class A:

```
b = new B(5); // where 5 is an int data member of B
c = new C();
```

and let B::bee() be a function I would need to access from C() BUT, I would need to access members of B (not a new instance of B) created by A.

```
So C::getIntfromB(){
  b->getInt();
}
```

Or something.

I've tried going for:

```
b = new B(5);
c = new C(*b);
```

having a `B b;` private member for C

However for some reason I simply cannot get it to work properly, what is the obvious error I am making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `C` member should be a pointer or a reference (`B *b` or `B &b`). If it's a `B` it will copy your `B` object, so it will refer to a different instance (which has been created by copying the one you're interested into).

Also, you'll need to pass your `b` object as a pointer or a reference, otherwise a new instance will be created while passing the parameter, and your pointer/reference in `C` class will refer to that one. (This would also lead to other problems, since such copy would be a temporary getting destroyed as soon as `C`'s constructor returns)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your object **C** can't access correct data from object **B** is because **C** has its own copy of object **B'** instead of reference to existing peer object **B**.